# Why can't i type a float as an integer in my f-string

Tags: python, file

I had a class that was already connected to a csv file so i couldnt add 'marathon' there.

> The query was that
> a club wants to display the number of whole marathons each member has   walked.  A marathon is 26.22 miles long.
>
> An example of the calculation required is:
>
> If Nikolai Bryant walks 145.6 miles this equates to:
> 145.6/26.22 miles = 5.59115179 marathons
> Nikolai has therefore walked 5 whole marathons.
>
> In the above example ‘Nikolai,Bryant,5’ would be stored.
>
> Write “The number of whole marathons walked by each member is” to the results.txt file
>
> Start loop for each record in members() array
>
> Calculate the number of whole marathons walked
>
> Write the forename, surname and the number of whole marathons to the results.txt file and loop
>
> Close the results.txt file

I had this which tried to make marathon a new variable since adding it to the class not in this code would've caused an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3jUN.png)

```
def output_it(members, furthest):
  of=open("results.txt", "a")
  of.write('The number of whole marathons walked is:\n')
  for loop in range(len(members)):
    int(marathon=round(1, members[loop].distance/26.22))
    of=open("results.txt", "a")
    of.write(f'{members[loop].forename} {members[loop].surname} {marathon}')
    
#Meinne programme
members=read_data_to_AOT()
furthest=find_furthest_distance(members)
display_fursthest_distance_walked(furthest, members)
output_it(members, furthest)
```

Comment: Can you explain what `int(marathon=round(...))` is supposed to be doing?

Comment: Well, you probably want to move `marathon=` out of `int()`.

Comment: you want to cast the float result into int first and then assign it to marathon variable. What you're doing is assigning float to marathon and then casting the expression (not just the assignment) which does not make sense. You can get away with `members[loop].distance // 26.22` instead of rounding and casting to int etc. The `//` will output the characteristic value of the output of the expression. i.e `3/2 is 1.5` but `3//2 is 1`. And btw your `round()` function is wrong. You swapped the arguments.

Comment: round function takes two arguments (number,digit) , 
int(marathon=round( members[loop].distance/26.22),1),i think that what you need to avoid getting the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line doesn't seem valid to me. `marathon` is not an argument of `int()`; this code is not creating a variable called `marathon` as far as I know. `int()` returns an int, but you're not even doing anything with the returned value. You're just throwing it away:

```
int(marathon=round(1, members[loop].distance/26.22))
```

It seems that you meant to do:

```
marathon = int(round(1, members[loop].distance / 26.22))
```

Also, having [magic numbers](https://codeburst.io/software-anti-patterns-magic-numbers-7bc484f40544) in your code is an anti-pattern. Instead, I would define the number somewhere above, like:

```
# A marathon is 42.195 kilometers, or 26 miles, 385 yards:
MILES_PER_MARATHON = 26.0 + (385 * 3 / 5280)
```

Then, your code would make more sense to an uninformed reader:

```
marathon = int(round(1, members[loop].distance / MILES_PER_MARATHON))
```

Comment: it was the marathon = int(round(1, members[loop].distance / 26.22)) that i needed

Comment: There is a csv file with all the distances so it would make more sense if you had the full code but i only needed that part.